# How to store URLs in Elasticsearch for fast access?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to use Elasticsearch for a website and need a fast way to retrieve documents via the page's URL strings - actually paths (e.g. `/shoes/sneakers/nike`). The paths are unique.

Following solutions come to my mind:

1. Store as string, indexed, not analyzed
2. Store in the _id field

Which one would be the better solution and are there maybe better methods?

Thanks!

Comment: first one is actually okay. I don't think you need it to be analysed

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "url": "/shoes/sneakers/nike"
        }
    }
}
```

You need to store url field with their values. This match_phrase will solve your problem.

Comment: Definitely not. Docs say: "The match_phrase query analyzes the text and creates a phrase query out of the analyzed text". Better would be a term query: "The term query finds documents that contain the exact term specified in the inverted index.". But the term query also doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the url field as keyword datatype and use the below query to get the results.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/keyword.html

```
POST index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "url": "/shoes/sneakers/nike"
        }
    }
}
```

if you store it as text data type then elasticsearch will automatically create a keyword field for you and you can use the below query to get the results

mapping created by Elasticsearch

```
"url": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
}
```

query to search

```
POST index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "url.keyword": "/shoes/sneakers/nike"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why would you want ignore above 256 on a url? urls can be longer than that and if you want to index the whole thing you probably should drop that setting.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. it was created automatically by dynamic mapping rules which overrides the default value by setting ignore_above: 256.